# Bogomolov-Beauville-Fujiki form, algebraically

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact hyperkahler manifold, i.e. a manifold with three 
complex structures $I,J,K$ defining an action of quaternions on the
tangent bundle and a metric which is Kahler with respect to all 
three structures, of complex dimension $2n$. Then (theorem due to B,B,F) there exists a unique up to a sign quadratic form $q$ on $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ such that for any class $\alpha \in H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$
$$
q(\alpha)^n = \int_M \alpha^{2n}
$$

Let $\omega_I, \omega_J, \omega_K$ be Kahler forms with respect to 
the three complex structures, then $\sigma=\omega_J + i\omega_K$ is holomorphic non-degenerate 2-form on $(M,I)$. Conversely, given a holomorphic non-degenerate 2-form $\sigma$ on a compact Kahler manifold $(M,I)$, one can define complex structures $J, K$ so that $\sigma$ arises as above. This makes holomorphically symplectic and hyperkahler manifolds two representations of the same object.

Now let $X$ be a projective algebraic variety of dimension $2n$ over a field $k$ with an algebraic non-degenerate 2-form. Is there an algebraic analogue of the form $q$? More precisely, is there a quadratic form $q$ on the Neron-Severi group of $X$ such that for any class $C \in NS(X)$ 
$$
q(C)^n=C \cdot \ldots \cdot C
$$
(intersection $2n$ times on the right)?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking about this primarily in cases when $k$ has positive characteristic, and thus we cannot use the Lefschetz principle?

Comment: I wonder if a purely algebraic definition of $q$ is possible (just like existence of Hodge decomposition on algebraic de Rham cohomology can be proved by the use of Leschetz principle, but there is an algebraic proof of this fact due to Deligne and Illusie). Of course it is interesting to know if the fact is true in positive characteristic.

Comment: The Deligne-Illusie method can only apply to schemes that lift over the Witt vectors (at least modulo $p^2$).  Are you willing to restrict to those schemes that lift over the Witt vectors?  The point is, we do not even know whether Fano manifolds lift over the Witt vectors, so I suspect there are no results about hyperKaehler manifolds lifting over the Witt vectors.